can't connect to gcp VM via external client SSH
I can connect to this Debian VM via browser SSH, or via gcloud using:
gcloud compute ssh mywebsrv123
But I can't connect via filezilla, or MobaXterm, these are the error messages I get:

MobaXterm: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:
publickey)
Filezilla: Server refused our key

I'm on windows 10, I've create the ssh pair using ssh-keygen command, and I've added the content of the .pub file to the VM's SSH Keys. When I try to connect I indicate the private key file in the ssh client.

update: I've tried an older SSH key pair and it worked, I don't know why the new ones don't work
the difference I see between old (working) and new ssh .pub file is at the end:
the old one has the email username of my GCP account mygcpacc@gmail.com
while the new one has the my windows username@pcname

What key format? What is the remote version of ssh? What debian release?

both old and new key .pub file start with ssh-rsa , Debian 12 on the VM, on my desktop if I run ssh -v localhost I get OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

I tried generating a new key, this time specifying username and other options like in the gcp docs: ssh-keygen -t rsa -f gcpkey2 -C mygcpemail@gmail.com -b 2048
and this time it works;
last time when it didn't work I called ssh-keygen without any options
